# How to know the layout of a structure data in c

Tags: c++, c, memory, struct

I have a structure as below :

```
struct A{
         int a;
         int b;
         char c;
};
```

I would like to know the memory address of a member in reference with the structure. I need to write a function or a macro inorder to get the following results.

```
 myfun( A , c ) ---> (4 + 4 - 1) 7
 myfun( A , b ) ---> (4 -1) 3 
 myfun( A , a ) ---> 0
```

Is there anyway guys ?

Note : Should pass only the structure name and a member name to the function ( myfun) . You are not allowed to create variables and pass it to the function. However you are allowed to do anything within in the function.

Comment: @EliBendersky can you write the function/macro so that it will be useful for everyone to understand how to use it.

Comment: He talks about the _standard_ macro: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof

Comment: You want your macros to add together all the previous numbers and characters in the structure?

Comment: Yeah thats true i have to use offsetof . Thanks @EliBendersky for pointing out.

Comment: @EliBendersky: Answer section: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Answer (score 0):

That's what the [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro does. It's already part of C++.

Comment: Is there UB in that "possible implementation"? o.O